# Length contraction experienced by a person "at rest"?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

If a person was riding a train going .999C tword a person standing on the train track, and the train track and everything on it were the only things in the universe, the person on the train would see the person on the track stretched out due to length contraction, but would the person on the track see the train stretched out? If so, why do galaxies moving away from us very quickly not look stretchy to us?

Comment: Contraction makes the length shorter, not stretched out.

Comment: It appears this question was edited after my answer was accepted, to include the additional question about non-stretched galaxies (which PM 2Ring correctly notes should be a question about non-squished galaxies). This should be a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two frames. The track frame has the track and the person on the tracks. The train frame has the train and the person on the train. The person on the tracks measures the proper length of the tracks and a length-contracted train and passenger. The person on the train measures the proper length of the train and a length-contracted track and pedestrian.

The apparent contradiction between the two frames about the length of track in contact with the train's wheels is a relativity of simultaneity problem. "The front of the train crosses railroad tie number $n$" is an event in one place, "the back of the train crosses railroad tie number $m$" is an event in a different place, and therefore different frames will disagree about the displacement in time between these events.